# How to prove a statement of A or B implies C?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am trying to prove a statement of the form "($A$ or $B$) implies $C$".

During my attempt to do so, I have shown that "($A$ but not $B$) implies $C$" and "($B$ but not $A$) implies $C$".

This leaves one last case to prove: "($A$ and $B$) implies $C$".

I think there may be a simple way to avoid having to prove the last statement explicitly, perhaps by making a contradiction with the preceding two proofs.

Is there any way to prove the last one using the first two results, without having to use any further details of what $A$, $B$, and $C$ are?

(or is it sufficient to show the first two statements?)

Comment: Can you  derive it from A implies C?

Comment: @justabit Without "not B", that seems impossible.

Comment: By "$A$ or $B$  implies $C$," do you  mean $(A\lor B)\implies C$ or $A\lor (B\implies C)$?

Comment: @kandb Sorry for the ambiguity. I mean the formal stat $(A\;or\;B) \Rightarrow C$

Comment: @MinChulPark I've rewritten for clarity - would you mind checking if the rewrite reflects what you intended to ask, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(A\land\lnot B)\land(\lnot A\land B)\to (A\land B) $$

The LHS is always false, and so the truth of the RHS is indeterminate.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answers the question either - I don't even see how it's *relevant* to the question. Where did you get the LHS from? "And"-ing together two of the hypotheses the OP mentions is certainly a thing you can do, but could you explain why you did it? (The fact that I received three downvotes suggests that I've missed something, but I really don't see what, I'm afraid.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens; the idea is that both premises are true, therefore the RHS is true. The material implication operator returns true whether the RHS is true or false. and so knowing the result of the operation doesn't determine the RHS, i.e. implication is not successful.

Comment: @PatrickStevens; I thought your answer was ok, so I've upvoted it to make you feel better! You probably need an example of when it is true.

Comment: Thanks - I'll add one in (I left it out originally because the OP was asking "can I use this method" and the answer is "no, and here is why". It's not actually necessary to show that the method sometimes gives the right answer by coincidence.)

Comment: I don't see why both premises are true, though. The OP hasn't shown that *either* premise is true, let alone both (and indeed you've shown that they can't both be true). They've only shown that either premise implies $C$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens; OP asks if A'B & AB' implies AB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142794/discussion-between-jmp-and-patrick-stevens).

Comment: Nicely concise answer!

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to use the fact that

\begin{equation*}
(D\implies E)\Longleftrightarrow\left[(\neg D)\lor E\right]
\end{equation*}

Then you can write

\begin{align*}
\left[(A\lor B)\implies C\right]&\Longleftrightarrow\left[\neg(A\lor B)\lor C\right]\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\left(\left[(\neg A)\land(\neg B)\right]\lor C\right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\left[(\neg A)\lor C\right]\land\left[(\neg B)\lor C\right]\\
&\Longleftrightarrow (A\implies C)\land(B\implies C).
\end{align*}

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP has proved neither $A \implies C$ nor $B \implies C$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I'm trying to give OP an idea of what correct deductions might look like, but maybe I haven't done so in the best way. I think my answer does answer him, though, albeit not directly. Incidentally, I doubt he's proved what he says he's proved, in which case your answer isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: General policy is surely to answer the question they asked, and possibly to note that you suspect they have asked the wrong question, rather than to ignore the question they asked completely. I certainly see no evidence at all to support the assertion "Your deductions aren't correct"; do you have any? I'm surprised everyone seems to think it's so unlikely that the OP is attempting a simple case-bash on the three cases "$A$ but not $B$" ,"$B$ but not $A$", and "both $A$ and $B$". The OP has asked whether it is necessary to bash the third case, and in fact it *is* necessary, as my answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is impossible. Let $A$ be "the number $n$ is even", $B$ be "the number $m$ is even", and $C$ be "exactly one of $n$ or $m$ is even". Then "$A$ but not $B$" implies $C$, and "$B$ but not $A$" implies $C$, but "$A$ and $B$" can be true when $C$ is false (let $m = n = 2$).

(It can, of course, be the case that "$A$ and $B$" is true and also $C$ is true. Let $C$ be any true statement to show this; or alternatively let $C$ instead be the hypothesis "at least one of $n$ or $m$ is even" in the above example.)

Comment: It would probably be better to explicitly construct a propositional valuation where this fails. Also note that while you answered OP’s question about ‘and’ the original question was about ‘or’.

Comment: Sorry, please assume that I'm misunderstanding something very fundamental, because I clearly believe something different to everyone else who has interacted on this question. Their question was indeed about "or", and they have split the "A or B" case into three: "A and B", "not A and B", and "A and not B". They say they have dealt with the latter two cases, leaving only the former case, the "and" case. I don't see how this fails to be an answer.

Comment: I agree with you, though it may be better spell out to the OP why what you have shown implies that the information they provided is not enough to answer their original question. I have upvoted to compensate for your downvotes without explanation.

Comment: Your answer is correct too.