# A proof of "(not A and not B) implies (not C)"

Tags: logic, proof-writing

This is a revision of the question in [How to prove a statement of A or B implies C?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637016/how-to-prove-a-statement-of-a-or-b-implies-c).

I corrected the given conditions.

Suppose that we have the following conditions:

$$\neg A\wedge B\Rightarrow\neg C$$

$$A\wedge\neg B\Rightarrow\neg C$$

$$A \wedge B \Rightarrow C \quad (*)$$

By using these conditions, can we prove that $\neg A \wedge \neg B  \Rightarrow \neg C$  ?.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Not when $C\iff (A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation $$(A,B,C)=(0,0,1)$$ shows that your given conclusion is not derivable from your given premises.